# Looping through File1.txt and File2.txt is really slow. Both files are 280MB

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I have 2 large text files with 400,000 lines of text in each file. In File2.txt, I need to find the line containing the userId from the current line in File1.txt. Once I've located the correct line in File2.txt, I do some calculations and write the line to a new text file.

The code I've created to do this runs really slow. I've tried rewriting it various ways but it always chugs along and never finishes. How can I do this fast?

```
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {        
    string line1 = "";
    string line2 = "";

    //the new text file we are creating. Located in IVR_Text_Update\bin\Debug
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewFile.txt");

    //the new text file which contains the registrants which need removing
    StreamWriter sw_removeRegs = new StreamWriter("RemoveRegistrants.txt");

    //address has changed so we write the line to the address file
    StreamWriter sw_addressChange = new StreamWriter("AddressChanged.txt");

    List<string> lines_secondFile = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog2.FileName)) {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            lines_secondFile.Add(line);
        }
    }

    //loop through the frozen file one line at a time
    while ((line1 = sr1.ReadLine()) != null) {
        //get the line from the update file, assign it to line2
        //function accepts (userId, List)
        line2 = getLine(line1.Substring(3, 8), lines_secondFile);

        //if line2 is null then userId was not found therefore we write
        //the line to Remove Registrants file
        if (line2 == null) {
            sw_removeRegs.Write(line1 + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        //address between the two lines was found to be different so we still write
        //them to the new text file but don't update codes
        else if (line1.Substring(93, 53) != line2.Substring(93, 53)) {
            sw_addressChange.Write(line1 + Environment.NewLine);
            sw.Write(line1 + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        //test for null then write the new line in our new text file
        else if ((line1 != null) && (line2 != null)) {
            sw.Write(line1.Substring(0, 608) +                    
                     line2.Substring(608, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(617, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(626, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(635, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(644, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(653, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(662, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(671, 9) +
                     line2.Substring(680, 9) +

                     line1.Substring(680, 19) + 
                     Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    textBox1.Text = "Finished.";
    sr1.Close();
    sw.Close();
    sw_removeRegs.Close();
    sw_addressChange.Close();
}

//returns the line from the update file which has the corresponding userId
//from the frozen file
string getLine(string userId, List<string> lines_secondFile) {

    foreach (string currentLine in lines_secondFile) {
        if (currentLine.Contains(userId)) {
            return currentLine;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: disk reads take a long time.  You can always write stuff to the console periodically to let you know that your application is doing something.

Comment: you might want to add some self-documenting variable names, your current code is quite cryptic ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of reading it line by line, try reading all of the file at once. This is much faster than making many read requests to a file. This is because file access is much slower than memory access. Try [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

With that said, you should try profiling the code to see exactly where the bottleneck in the code is.

Comment: How do I read a text file all at once? After removing most of my code, I have narrowed it down to my loop within a loop being the bottleneck.

Comment: Using ReadAllText causes an OutofMemoryException error because the files are too large, 280MB.

Answer (score 4):

Not taking into account disk access speed your current algorithm is `O(n^2)` - for each line in the first file you are doing a lookup in a *list* to find the user id - you can use some caching to avoid looking up the *same* user id multiple times, I assume you have less than 400k users, so duplicates should be the majority of the cases:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> userMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string getLine(string userId, List<string> lines_secondFile) 
{
    if(userMap.ContainsKey(userId))
        return userMap[userId];
    else
    {
      foreach (string currentLine in lines_secondFile) 
      {
        if (currentLine.Contains(userId)) 
        {
            userMap.Add(userId, currentLine);
            return currentLine;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resources, you can put the entire file(s) in memory. Then speed should be increased.  Prior to C# 4 you had to use the WIN32 API to memory map a file, but C# 4 added `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile`.

One could also implement a multiple thread approach to process parts of the file in pararrel, but that will add additional complexity.